# Insert list values into another list (python)

Tags: python, list

I'm still pretty new at programming.
I have a two Lists:

```
List1=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
List2=['a','b','c']
```

and I want to put the values of one list into the other one, so my output looks like this:

```
List1=[[1,2,3,4,'a'],[5,6,7,8,'b'],[9,10,11,12,'c']]
```

So far I managed to write this:

```
for i in range(0,len(List1)):
    for row in List1:
        row.insert(5, List2[i])
```

But i get this:

```
List1=[[1,2,3,4,'a','b','c'],[5,6,7,8,'a','b','c'],[9,10,11,12,'a','b','c']]
```

I'm sure it's probably a simple mistake, but I can't find out what it is.

Comment: `for row in list:`, what is `list`? also, you're missing a closing `)`.

Comment: Sorry list is List1, i'll edit it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your posted code very explicitly adds *every* letter to *each* list.  Instead, you want to add only the corresponding letter.  You need one loop index for both lists, not nested loops.

```
for i in range(len(List1)):
    List1[i].append(List2[i])
```

Comment: what a coincidence :o

Comment: I typed faster!  :-)

Comment: Well I checked in python interpreter before comment :)

Comment: Thank you both for your answer! What if I want to choose the index where to insert List2?

Comment: Then you revert to `insert`, as in your original code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` for that:

```
List1=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
List2=['a','b','c']

List1 = [ a + list(b) for a, b in zip(List1, List2)]
print(List1)
```

Out:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'a'], [5, 6, 7, 8, 'b'], [9, 10, 11, 12, 'c']]
```

Please be aware, that this creates a new list and does not change the old one. If lists mutability is used this code will not work!

Comment: This creates a third list, though (`List3`) instead of modifying `List1`, as asked by OP.

Comment: Depending, if OP is working with the list as a mutable object it makes a difference, you are right, changed code, so that `List1` is now there instead of `List3`, but might still cause problems, if list is supposed to be changed in function. Added info to answer, thanks

Comment: It might also be a problem in terms of performance as all the items of `List1` are copied to a temporary value (expressed by your list comprehension) before the "old" list that `List1` used to refer to is freed, in order to allow the assignment. This means that the values `1`, `2`, ... are unnecessarily copied.

Answer (score 1):

You can use append to just add the ith indexed element to each element of List1

```
for i in range(len(List1)):
    List1[i].append(List2[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for row, char in zip(List1, List2):
    row.append(char)
```

which gives:

```
>>> List1
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'a'], [5, 6, 7, 8, 'b'], [9, 10, 11, 12, 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator:

```
it = iter(List2)
for lst in List1:
    lst.append(next(it))
```